# HTML-Element appears in dialog-windows though s4-notdlg is set

Tags: master-page, custom-masterpage

I have a customized sharepoint masterpage. The basic structure is the starter master pages from codeplex.

So i did my customizing and unfortunately some of the elements appear in the dialog windows though i added the "s4-notdlg" class to everyone of these elements.

I wrapped a new div-container around all content starting from the ribbon row to the end of the scrolling area because i needed to adjust width, and min-height borders etc.

Of course if i add the s4-notdlg to this container there won't be much to see in the dialog box.. But since my searchbox appears though - i have the s4-notdlg class added specifically to it but it appears nontheless.. any ideas? source and pics could be provided..

Comment: Do you have any unclosed tags? Maybe some CSS which overrides it and makes it fail in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar (F12) you can select the object that is not hiding correctly to see all of the CSS attributes assigned to it and find out what is overriding your class.

Comment: Apparently the s4-notdlg class only works properly if its the only class.. i added to these containers custom classes which caused the wrong behaviour..

Comment: From what I know it needs to be the first class, not required to be the only one

Answer (score 1):

Actually Peter, s4-notdlg does not have to be the only CSS class. These examples:

http://blog.drisgill.com/2009/11/sp2010-branding-tip-2-custom-master.html

http://erikswenson.blogspot.com/2010/11/hide-custom-code-within-sp-2010-modal.html

clearly use more than one CSS class. It's being overridden by something else.

## Edit:

[“s4-notdlg” not doing what it should be doing](http://blog.kuppens-switsers.net/2011/10/s4-notdlg-not-doing-what-it-should-be-doing/) suggests verifying that the html tag in the master page includes `runat="server"` as a resolution to this issue.